# Why does the return value of getCurrentLattitude() throws number format exception?

Tags: android, exception

I have tried something like below

```
double latitude = 0;
double longitude = 0;  

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.places_details_gridview);

    locManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    currentLoc = new CurrentLocation(locManager, ShowPlacesInList.this);

    if(currentLoc.getCurrentLattitude() != null && currentLoc.getCurrentLongitude() != null){   
        latitude = Double.parseDouble(currentLoc.getCurrentLattitude());
        longitude = Double.parseDouble(currentLoc.getCurrentLongitude());               
        myLoc = new Location("");
        myLoc.setLatitude(latitude);
        myLoc.setLongitude(longitude);
        calculateDist();
    }  
}
```

It showing number format exception  in the

```
latitude = Double.parseDouble(currentLoc.getCurrentLattitude());
```

from currentLoc.getLatitude and currentloc.getLongitude i am getting a string value

Comment: What is the value being returned that cannot be parsed?

Comment: check the value of currentLoc.getCurrentLattitude() .. you will get the answer

Comment: String value that you'r passing to Double.parseDouble() is not in the correct format. Print it in logcat and post here.

Comment: Please print the values returned from `getCurrentLattitude()` and `getCurrentLongitude()` and [add those to your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20567103/edit).

Comment: print value of currentLoc.getCurrentLattitude() using log, and see the monster! :P

Comment: "*currentloc.getLongitude i am getting a string value*" And what String are you getting??

Answer (score 0):

Please read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).

Make sure that you are using correct decimal separator (depending on Locale valid Double may be 5.0 or 5,0).

Answer (score 0):

> from currentLoc.getLatitude and currentloc.getLongitude i am getting a string value

What string value?

The parseDouble method throws a NumberFormatException when "the string does not contain a parsable double" -http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)

The NumberFormatException that is thrown will show you exactly what the problem is e.g.:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "A5.0"